# Is there any way to make recursive async calls in Swift untill the call retrieve all pages?

Tags: ios, swift, api, asynchronous

The thing is that I have a method that makes requests to the backend, internally the backend saves itself the page retrieved so you only have to call recursively untill it returns a flag that lets you know there isn't more data.

My question is: Is there any way to make recursive async calls untill retrieve all data form the backend?

My code:

```
func fetchAllDataSource( completionHandler: @escaping (TFResult<[Model?]?, TFNServerError>) -> Void ) {
    
            if !sourceMore {
                completionHandler(.success(nil))
            }
    
            self.fetchDataSource{ response in
    
                    switch response {
                        case .success(let array):
                            if let array = array {
                                self.sourceItemsAll.append(contentsOf: array.compactMap{$0})
                                return
                            } else {
                                completionHandler(.success(nil))
                                return
                            }
                    break
                    case .error(let error):
                        completionHandler(.error(error))
                        return
                    break
    
                    }
                }
            } }
```

Then:

```
  var sourceItemsAll = [Model]() {
    didSet {
        if !sourceStart {
        self.fetchAllDataSource{_ in }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code the completionHandler is called bun never comes back

Comment: You are not calling completiin handler after appending and there is no real recursion.

Comment: Correct @Sulthan. This is because there is more data to be retrieved from the backend. Let's say there are many pages. So you have to call it recursively untill `fetchDataSource` returns no array.

Comment: But you are also not calling fetchDatasource, which is need to get the next part of the data. Also, your "sourceMore" is not being set anywhere.

Comment: @johnelemans it exisst but os noth there. Just is the call with the clousure.

Comment: @johnelemans si the firts call is not there but the rest of the calls until completion are performed via didSet in the variable sorceItemsAll